# IpadOS with Overleaf or other online editors

Tags: overleaf, ipad

I have one of the new iPad pro devices that released last year however I am not currently using the iPadOS beta that is now live. My question relates to Overleaf and other online editors -- differentiating it from the recent question asking for which "app based" editors there are.

I have tried to use Overleaf on the iPad a few times to tex up a mathematics PDF, but it seems a bit buggy as the mobile based Safari browser doesn't seem to scroll properly and sometimes the cursor locks up or moves to the wrong place causing text entry issues. I also noticed that it was in general difficult to move the cursor in the Overleaf editor window even using the Apple pencil.

My question is twofold: first, does the new desktop class Safari browser combined with the new text navigation get rid of these quirks? Secondly, is it perhaps something I'm doing wrong that is causing the behavior described above in Overleaf when I use the iPad?

Finally, it is possible this would be a question better suited for the Apple based Ask Different site so I will gladly move it if that is a concern.

Comment: Overleaf's customer support is [very friendly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226/liantze-lim) and should be able to help you here